# Does AlarmManager works in background even if app is killed? or we have to use Services for that?

Tags: android, kotlin, alarmmanager

Actually i have implemented AlarmApp in which i want to show notification after some seconds(that user passes) using AlarmManager...now in this case alarm works perfectly fine if app is not killed but i want to implement like we use alarm apps in our mobile phone....

dataclass AlarmItem-

```
data class AlarmItem(
    val message : String ,
    val time : LocalDateTime
)
```

interface AlarmScheduler

```
interface AlarmScheduler {
    fun schedule(item: AlarmItem)
    fun cancelAlarm(item: AlarmItem)
}
```

here is code of AndroidAlarmScheduler class which is implemented from AlarmScheduler interface..

```
class AndroidAlarmScheduler (private val context: Context) : AlarmScheduler {

    private val alarmManager = context.getSystemService(AlarmManager::class.java)

    override fun schedule(item: AlarmItem) {
        val intent = Intent(context , AlarmReceiver::class.java).apply {
            putExtra("EXTRA_MSG" , item.message)
        }

        //alarm triggered at exact given time and also in low power mode
        alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(
            AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            item.time.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toEpochSecond()*1000,
            PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                context,
                item.hashCode(),
                intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE
            )
        )
        Toast.makeText(context,"Alarm set!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }

    override fun cancelAlarm(item: AlarmItem) {
        alarmManager.cancel(
            PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                context,
                item.hashCode(),
                Intent(context,AlarmReceiver::class.java),
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE
            )
        )
        Toast.makeText(context,"Alarm canceled!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
}
```

Alarm Receiver class

```
class AlarmReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    private val CHANNEL_ID = "channelID"
    private val NOTIFICATION_ID = 100
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        val message = intent?.getStringExtra("EXTRA_MSG") ?: return
        println("Alarm triggered!: $message")
        context?.let {
            val notificationManager = context.getSystemService(NotificationManager::class.java)
            val notification =
                NotificationCompat.Builder(context).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
                    .setContentText("Wake up!").setContentTitle("AlarmManager")
                    .setChannelId(CHANNEL_ID)
                    .build()
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(
                NotificationChannel(
                    CHANNEL_ID,
                    "ChannelName",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
                )
            )
            notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID,notification)
        }



    }
}
```

and final mainActivity code-

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        var alarmItem : AlarmItem? = null
        val scheduler = AndroidAlarmScheduler(this)
        binding.scheduleBtn.setOnClickListener {
            alarmItem = AlarmItem(
                time = LocalDateTime.now().plusSeconds(binding.time.text.toString().toLong()),
                message = binding.message.text.toString()
            )
            alarmItem?.let{scheduler.schedule(it)}
            binding.time.text = null
            binding.message.text = null

        }

            binding.cancelBtn.setOnClickListener {
            alarmItem?.let {
                scheduler.cancelAlarm(it)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I was expecting it will work even if app is killed..

Answer (score 0):

The behavior of AlarmManager when an app is killed in Android depends on the type of alarm that is set.

If you set the alarm with the RTC_WAKEUP (as in your case) or ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP type and your app is killed, the alarm will still trigger the next time the device wakes up. This is because these types of alarms are designed to wake up the device from sleep to deliver their intent.

On the other hand, if you set the alarm with the RTC or ELAPSED_REALTIME type and your app is killed, the alarm will not trigger until the next time the app is launched. This is because these types of alarms are not designed to wake up the device from sleep.

Comment: but in my case i am not getting notification if apps gets killed..... so what is going wrong here?

Comment: @Younes Charfaoui Yeah but how about if the device wakes up without reopening the app for example when user interacting another app then will alarmManager get triggered?